# Weird crash on iOS using Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

Firebase Crashlytics shows a weird crash on iOS app, I can't understand what causing it:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  LogoQuizAC                     0x10047f6a0 _hidden#18_ + 135 (__hidden#957_:135)
1  LogoQuizAC                     0x1004771f4 _hidden#17_ + 96 (__hidden#454_:96)
2  LogoQuizAC                     0x100477328 _hidden#20_ + 4304712488 (__hidden#456_:4304712488)
3  Foundation                     0x19b094b20 __NSFireTimer + 68
4  CoreFoundation                 0x199c79fa0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
5  CoreFoundation                 0x199c79ba0 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1064
6  CoreFoundation                 0x199c78ffc __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 328
7  CoreFoundation                 0x199c72ee4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1936
8  CoreFoundation                 0x199c7221c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
9  GraphicsServices               0x1b183e784 GSEventRunModal + 164
10 UIKitCore                      0x19c6b2ee8 -[UIApplication _run] + 1072
11 UIKitCore                      0x19c6b875c UIApplicationMain + 168
12 LogoQuizAC                     0x1002b503c main + 20 (RLockedCell.swift:20)
13 libdyld.dylib                  0x1999326b0 start + 4
```

[image]

How can I figure it out? any strategy of solving this issue?

Comment: You check crash reports on the Apple site in your account. Also, you can view crashes via `Xcode -> Window -> Organizer` choose your build and version and maybe there is some more information there.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Apple site'? I tried to reproduce the crashes on my device but without any success.

Comment: You can go to `appstoreconnect.apple.com` and see crash statistic there, but for more info about crashes you need to check `Organizer`

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=nra79npr

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that such an amazing tool exists! But sadly I couldn't find the cause of the crash it self. In the Organizer -> Crashes I couldn't find the answer, the bug shows exactly as I pasted here above... No clue.

Comment: Do you have any timers, maybe a timer somewhere here `RLockedCell`? Also, can you download the production build of your application from a store and find a place where its crashes?

Comment: I don't have any timers in the app. Maybe it's AppLovinSDK or AdMobSDK related. Also i've downloaded the production build from the AppStore but it seems that everything is working smooth. I can't see anything.

Comment: Still can't figure out what to do.. Any ideas?